# ParamQuery: How to handle events with multiple grids?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ParamQuery to load grids on a web page.

I have two grids in selector `#tabela`:

- $objOrcamento is the main grid
- $grid is the details grid

Now I want to handle events like `cellBeforeSave`, `load`, etc for both of them but I keep receiving the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'pqGrid'
```

For example, to handle `cellBeforeSave` in `$grid`, I tried:

```
var $grid={
   //colModel, dataModel, etc...

  cellBeforeSave: function (evt, ui) {
            var isValid = $grid.pqGrid("isValid", ui);
            if (!isValid.valid) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }

   },
}
```

This isn't working, so I've tried outside `var $grid`:

```
$("#tabela").on("pqgridcellbeforesave", function (event, ui) {
        var isValid = $grid.pqGrid("isValid", ui);
        if (!isValid.valid) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
});
```

But this is generating the same error.
What is the correct way to handle events in multiple grids?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$grid` is *not* the grid, it just contains the options used to initialize the pqgrid plugin.

Try something more like this:

```
$("#tabela").pqGrid({
   //colModel, dataModel, etc...

  cellBeforeSave: function (evt, ui) {

        // have to call pqgrid on a jquery object:
        var isValid = $("#tabela").pqGrid("isValid", ui);
        if (!isValid.valid) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
   },
});
```